# Can a Chrome Extension read what is typed by the user in text boxes?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can a Chrome Extension read what is typed by the user in text boxes? 
For example, text entered by the users in the Google Search bar or while the user is posting something on Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. It requires a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to access.